# How can I change the font color of text in the graph node in OrientDB studio?

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb-2.1

I am using orientDB version 2.2.3. I wanted to understand how could I change the font color for text in any node in the graph editor in the studio.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can only change `Fill` and `Stroke` colours in OrientDB Studio.

Comment: Is there no way to change the text color?